# In kony Textview2 content alignment to CONTENT_ALIGN_MIDDLE_RIGHT

Tags: android, textbox, focus, nexus-5, temenos-quantum

I have textbox 2 with the property content alignment to CONTENT_ALIGN_MIDDLE_RIGHT. So my content will stay at right.

But in nexus 5 when I type some value and close keyboard and again tap into textbox2, textbox is not get focus and goes up to the visible area.

If I make content alignment to CONTENT_ALIGN_MIDDLE_LEFT then it's working fine.

Do help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you please share the screenshots when CONTENT_ALIGN_MIDDLE_RIGHT and CONTENT_ALIGN_MIDDLE_LEFT applied

Comment: Edited my question with image.